# Yii2 события onclick

Tags: yii2

Yii2 только изучаю.
У меня в верстке есть ссылка Авторизация и мне нужно оставить ее в неизменном виде, только повесить на нее обработчик onclick что бы открыть всплывающую форму?

Answer (score 0):

почитай в доке о registerJs https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-assets
регистрация js кода во вьюхе.